# Any Time Function Guarantee to Return Different Values for Calls

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading

I am finding a time function which guarantees to return different values for different calls. I tried below method on LINUX, only to find that it is not what I want, it may return same value for calls from different threads.

```
   long GetTickCount()        
   {          
        struct timespec now;
        clock_gettime(MONOTONIC, &now);
        return now.tv_sec * 1000000000LL + now.tv_nsec;
   }
```

Is there any other way to do this on LINUX?

Comment: The first finding should be searching, right? And the most you get is a monotonic counter, which you must yourself augment with whatever info is neccessary to make it unique.

Comment: `MONOTONIC` doesn't guarantee getting different values for every call. That depends on the actual timing resolution.

Comment: Are you sure, you are solving the base problem, not a symptom? Why not use an interlocked counter?

Comment: In C++11 you can use `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()`, which may give you better resolution.

Answer (score 2):

Any clock is going to have limited granularity, which might cause successive calls to return the same value.  In order to solve that, you will need to use a global counter:

```
static long long previous_time = 0;

long long get_strictly_monotonic_time() {
    int rc;
    struct timespec tp;
    long long t;
    rc = clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &tp);
    if(rc < 0) return -1;
    t = tp.tv_sec * 1000000000LL + tp.tv_nsec;
    /* Critical region */
    if(t <= previous_time)
        t = previous_time + 1;
    previous_time = t;
    /* End of critical region */
    return t;
}
```

Since you want this to be reliable with multiple threads, you will need to protect the global counter with a global mutex (the region with the "Critical region" comments above).